# Find one unknown by using matlab

Tags: matlab

%Hello there. I have to solve one problem by using Matlab. I need your help please

```
m1=3;                %mass-1

m2=[0.25:0.25:3];    %mass-2 changing

f=[1:0.25:3]';       %frequency Hz

w=f*2*pi;            %natural frequency rad/s

k2all=(w.^2)*m2;     

k2=k2all(:,1);       %spring constant N/m


%I need to find k1 from the formula below:

w=(((k1+k2)*m2+k2*m1)/(2*m1*m2))+(0.5*sqrt((((k1+k2)*m2+m1*k2)/(m1*m2))^2-(((k1+k2)*k2-k2^2)/(m1*m2))));

%As you see m2,k2 and w are changing
```

Help please

Comment: What's the question...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming; you are not having problems with anything related to MATLAB, but rather, you are unable to solve an algebra problem. Try MathExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Computers aren't the answer to everything; you just need to solve a (relatively simple) algebra problem.

As I indicated in a comment, as such, this is not really a problem for Stack Overflow.

But let that be for future reference; for now, I'll save you some trouble. I'll use Unicode characters, both to avoid the problem of SO not having MathJax support, and to make 100% clear that it's not code.

Your original equation, with some extraneous brackets removed and some spacing added:

```
w = ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)/(2·m1·m2) + ...
    ½·√( (((k1+k2)·m2 + m1·k2)/(m1·m2))² - ((k1+k2)·k2 - k2²)/(m1·m2) );
```

multiply both sides by 2:

```
2·w = ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)/(m1·m2) + ...
      √( (((k1+k2)·m2 + m1·k2)/(m1·m2))² - ((k1+k2)·k2 - k2²)/(m1·m2) );
```

subtract the first term on the right hand side from both sides:

```
2·w - ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)/(m1·m2) = ...
      √( (((k1+k2)·m2+m1·k2)/(m1·m2))² - ((k1+k2)·k2 - k2²)/(m1·m2) );
```

square both sides:

```
( 2·w - ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)/(m1·m2) )² = ...
    (((k1+k2)·m2 + m1·k2)/(m1·m2))² - ((k1+k2)·k2 - k2²)/(m1·m2)
```

multiply both sides with `m1·m2`:

```
m1·m2·( 2w - ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)/(m1·m2) )² = ...
    ((k1+k2)·m2+m1·k2)²/(m1·m2) - (k1+k2)·k2 + k2²
```

expand the square on the left hand side, and carry out the multiplication with `m1·m2`:

```
 4·w²·m1·m2 - 4·w·((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1) + ((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1)²/(m1·m2) = ...
    ((k1+k2)·m2+m1·k2)²/(m1·m2) - (k1+k2)·k2 + k2²
```

Notice that the last term on the LHS equals the first term on the RHS. So you can just remove it:

```
4·w²·m1·m2 - 4·w·((k1+k2)·m2 + k2·m1) = -(k1+k2)·k2 + k2²
```

Expand and rearrange, so only the LHS contains terms with `k1`:

```
(k1+k2)·k2 - 4·w·(k1+k2)·m2 = 4·w·k2·m1 - 4·w²·m1·m2 + k2²
```

Rearrange:

```
(k1+k2)·(k2 - 4·w·m2) = 4·w·k2·m1 - 4·w²·m1·m2 + k2²
```

Divide by the second term on the LHS:

```
k1+k2 = (4·w·k2·m1 - 4·w²·m1·m2 + k2²) / (k2 - 4·w·m2)
```

and subtract `k2`:

```
k1 = (4·w·k2·m1 - 4·w²·m1·m2 + k2²) / (k2 - 4·w·m2)  - k2
```

simplify:

```
k1 = (k2·(m1+m2) - w·m1·m2) / (k2/(4·w) - m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The algebra is trivial here, as @RodyOldenhuis showed, but you can often simplify such processes by using symbolic math – it's also a useful way to check your answer (though you can still mistype the equations). Using [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
syms k1 k2 m1 m2 w
fun = ((k1+k2)*m2+k2*m1)/(2*m1*m2)+...
      0.5*sqrt((((k1+k2)*m2+m1*k2)/(m1*m2))^2-((k1+k2)*k2-k2^2)/(m1*m2));
k1 = solve(w==fun,k1)
```

This returns:

```
k1 =

(4*k2*m1*w - 4*m1*m2*w^2 + 4*k2*m2*w)/(k2 - 4*m2*w)
```

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: If you call `k1 = simplify(k1)`, it will factor out the `4*w`, but then it doesn't collect the `k2` terms either.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Mathematica works in similar ways. My guess is that this is because simplification can be expensive (especially years ago) so we get the first version of the answer that the solver obtains.